# Adding ArUco to Visual Studios community 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2017, aruco

I'm having problems implementing the aruco library to visual studios. I have already added OpenCV 3.2.0 without any problems. I have tried by downloading the newest aruco package (2.0.19) and the aruco package you can install via package manager console on visual studios. the package manager download the 1.2.4 version of aruco and opencv 2.4.8

I've tried to include it in my code, but without any luck
Can anyone help me?